# Global signaling in Pyside6?

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6

I would like to emit a signal in my main window and somewhere deep down in one of my components I would like to receive that signal. I have read in some thread here that can be solved with a common signal class, however I cannot make it work.

I created a signal Manager class with a test signal in it:

```
class Manager(QObject):
  test_signal = Signal(str)
  def __init__(self):
    QObject.__init__(self)
```

In my main window I do this:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
    self.signal_manager = SignalManager.Manager()
  def some_button_clicked(self):
    self.signal_manager.test_signal.emit('test')
```

Somewhere deep in one of the components:

```
class MyTreeWidget(QTreeWidget):
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    self.signal_manager = SignalManager.Manager()
    self.signal_manager.test_signal.connect(self.do_something)
  def do_something(self, param):
    # Do something...
```

So when I click my button and some_button_clicked emits the event do_something() should happen but it won't.
Wondering what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution wouldn't work, because you're always creating a *new* instance of the manager.

Whenever I need to rely on some "global" objects in a Qt program, I usually create a subclass of the QApplication and create attributes for them, which obviously also works for "global signals".

Then you can emit the signals or connect to them by accessing the application [`instance()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#instance):

```py
class MyApp(QApplication):
    globalSignal = pyqtSignal(str)


class TargetLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        QApplication.instance().globalSignal.connect(self.setText)


app = MyApp([])
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout(window)
lineEdit = QLineEdit()
layout.addWidget(lineEdit)
layout.addWidget(TargetLabel())

lineEdit.textChanged.connect(app.globalSignal)

window.show()
app.exec()
```

An alternative could be to use a global QObject subclass in a separate module, using a reference that is global to the module corresponding to a unique instance (one of the *rare* cases for which using `global` actually makes sense).

A possible "hacky" implementation would be to create a function named as the signal manager, and replace its global reference with an instance of the QObject, like the following example:

`globalsignal.py`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore

def GlobalSignalProxy():
    global GlobalSignalProxy
    if not isinstance(GlobalSignalProxy, QtCore.QObject):
        class GlobalSignalProxy(QtCore.QObject):
            signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
        # replace the function with the instance
        GlobalSignalProxy = GlobalSignalProxy()
    return GlobalSignalProxy
```

`targetlabel.py`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from globalsignal import GlobalSignalProxy

class TargetLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        GlobalSignalProxy().signal.connect(self.setText)
```

`main.py`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from globalsignal import GlobalSignalProxy
from targetlabel import TargetLabel

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)
lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
layout.addWidget(lineEdit)
lineEdit.textChanged.connect(GlobalSignalProxy().signal)
layout.addWidget(TargetLabel())
window.show()
app.exec()
```

The above could obviously be achieved with a singleton class too.

In any case, I wouldn't suggest this practice, as I believe that the QApplication subclass would be better for many reasons, including the fact that it's more appropriate for the OOP pattern.

Comment: Application instance worked great. Thanks!